# Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value using DELETE statement

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

```
int d1;
String attribute = comboBox1.getSelectedItem().toString(); // a combo box
System.out.println(attribute);
String data = t.getText(); // a textfield
System.out.println(data);
if (attribute.equals("COURSE_ID")) {
     IsNumber in = new IsNumber();
     d1 = in.stringToInt(data);
     
    try {
                            
        Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
        System.out.println("connection success!!");
                                                
        String sql = "DELETE FROM course WHERE ? = ?";
        PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
        statement.setString(1, attribute);
        statement.setInt(2, d1);
                            
        boolean rows = statement.execute();
        if (rows == true) {
            new ViewDatabase(user, name, pswrd);
            System.out.println("COURSE_ID UNIT UPDATE SUCCESSFUL!");
            frame.setVisible(false);
        } else if (rows == false) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Cannot find row!",
                      "ERROR", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
        
        statement.close();
        connection.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("& i oop");
            e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

For this piece of code, whenever I try to run it, it returns "Data truncation: Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'COURSE_ID'". I'm not sure what this is referring to and I searched and found some people saying that this error message is misleading, though I only found answers to selects, inserts, and updates, but not deletes.

I also turned off strict mode in MySQL, as advised from the internet, but to no avail.

Comment: Which line in the code throws the error?

Comment: @Chetan The error likely happens at the call to `execute()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *can't* bind strings to actual column names in a prepared statement.  So, the attribute column names must be hard-coded.  One pattern which might work would be:

```java
String sql = "";
if ("COL1".equals(attribute)) {
    sql = "DELETE FROM course WHERE COL1 = ?";
}
else if ("COL2".equals(attribute)) {
    sql = "DELETE FROM course WHERE COL2 = ?";
}
else {
    sql = "DELETE FROM course WHERE COL3 = ?";
}
PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
statement.setInt(1, d1);
boolean rows = statement.execute();
```